# Latin character not accepted into DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a Oracle DB which is configured for NLS_CHARCTERSET = 'US7ASCII' and hence it doesn't accepts UTF8 compliant.

Got to know a work around that we can use UNISTR() function to convert strings into desired characters. But, though I was able to see the output as '§' for following query:

SELECT  UNISTR('\00a7') FROM DUAL;

I was unable to insert that character into a column in the table whose type is VARCHAR2. I am seeing output as '?' after I try to insert that character. Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Use an `NVARCHAR2` data type instead of `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: What if you insert the '\0007' and when extracting use UNISTR().

Comment: @MT0: It worked for me. Thanks a ton!